# how to create an inventory summary report from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an inventory summary report for my inventory database and I'm getting confused as to how to do it. This is how my table looks like:

Stock_ID | Date | PO_ID | DR_ID | Product_ID | Stock_In | Stock_Out | Stock_Balance |

I want my output to look like this:

Product_ID Stock_Balance

1                    9000

2                              8000

3                              9000

4                              10000

5                              5000

6                              9000

7                              9000

8                              9000

I have used this sql script to generate the above output:

select Product_ID, Stock_Balance from stock_card

where Date = ( select max(Date) from stock_card )

group by Product_ID

Order by Product_ID, Stock_Balance

Unfortunately this script has a problem that when a product id's max date is lower than the others then it does not show up in the results.

Please help I'm new at using SQL and it's really confusing me.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows with the same dates, for a single product?

Comment: yes there can be multiple rows.

Comment: @darkxaldin In the case that there are 2 rows with productID:1 & date: 1/1/2011, Which of the rows do you want in your result?

Comment: How do you define *latest*, Does the `date` hold a time aswell? is there another auto-increment or sequence column? Please explain.

Comment: By latest I mean the latest row inserted into the database. Say that I first insert a row with product id 1 and date 1/1/2011 and then I insert another row with the same product id and date as the above. I want to get the one that I just inserted. Date column has time and stock id is auto increment.

Comment: @darkxaldin The auto-increment part was what i wanted to hear. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the grouping in a subquery, then find the matching row.

```
select Product_ID, Stock_Balance
FROM stock_card s JOIN (
    select MAX(Stock_ID) MaxID
    FROM stock_card
    GROUP BY Product_ID
  ) g ON s.Stock_ID = g.MaxID
Order by Product_ID, Stock_Balance
```

Comment: @darkxaldin Welcome to StackOverflow! (In the future, please post the table definition besides for the column names. As shown in this answer, the fact that `Stock_ID` is a auto-increment is important for us to know. Thanks)